# Determine if DLL or EXE is CLR or Native

Tags: .net, dll, binary, clr, exe

Im looking for a programtic way to determine if a DLL or EXE is native or CLR.  This must work for both 32-bit and 64-bit binaries.  Also it must look at the raw bytes of the file.

I don't think MS's algorithm always works.  Has anyone else had luck with this?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c91d4yzb.aspx

Comment: http://apichange.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/76c98b8c7311#ApiChange.Api/src/Introspection/CorFlagsReader.cs

Comment: Thanks that link helped alot!